# node_modules: symlink or not to symlink?

Tags: node.js, npm

My colleague has come to great idea in his opinion. He does not like paths that include many dotdot occurencies (more than 2 or 3). His idea is the following: use postinstall commands that would create symlinks to modules of interest in node_modules. This way you could require needed module something like that:

```
var some_module = require('some_module')
```

instead of

```
var some_module = require('../../../another/branch/some_module')
```

For me it seems like a dirty hack. One disadvantage I see is possible collision with built-in and npm modules. But it may be minor issue.

I have proposed another solution - to create separate module that would register modules of interest and reference them through it:

```
// a/branch/some_module.js
module.exports = 5
require('register')('some_module', module.exports)

// another/branch/interested_module.js
var some_module = require('register')('some_module') // 5
```

To be honest, both solutions seems ugly.

So, the question is, what is the proper way to solve the problem of deep deps?

Answer (score 1):

We use [node-app-root-path](https://github.com/inxilpro/node-app-root-path) to require local modules.

For example:

```
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');
var myModule = require(appRoot + '/lib/my-module.js');
```